# Localization using msi file

Tags: c#, windows-installer

In my application I want to support 2 languages (English and Arabic). For now I throw the English version of the help file in a certain path. What if I want the user choose the language he wants to install his application with and according to choose I'll throw the related chm file in that path.

Also another part of the Q, can I do something like when you install an application it asks you the language then it throws only the related `exe` file?

Comment: Can you explain which installation program you are using to generate the msi? Is it a Visual Studio setup project or something else?

Comment: ya i'm using visual studio 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell how you achieve localization in your application. Since you are developing in .NET I assume that you have a .resx file for every language containing all localized data. So why not install both help files and make the path to the help file a localized string in the resource file?

By the way, using localized resource files you will only have one executable to install. You can choose during the loading of your forms which language will be using by specifying the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` accordingly, e.g. based on a config setting or registry key.

Concerning the second part of your question: You can have your user select the target language. This would set the config setting or registry key described above. However, changing the language during installation would not change the UI language of the MSI installer (I don't think this is supported *).

I would therefore recommend you to have a separate installer for each language or use a different install system (NSIS seems to be a good choice).

*) MSI can [select the UI language automatically](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/) based on the Regional Settings defined for the user. However, this behaviour is not officially supported and teh way to achieve it is also a little complicated.